# Editing a question when it's most likely to be closed

Tags: discussion, questions, suggested-edits

Recently, I came across [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178455/pagination-using-next-and-prev-button) question. The grammar was in need of desperate help and so I suggested an edit. This question definitely does not belong on SE and is more appropriate for SO (even though I don't see it getting many answers there either). So, should I still be suggesting edits when I know that it will most likely be closed?

Comment: I edit deleted answers / closed questions all the time cause I can't stand it when people forget to format their code blocks.

Comment: @jamylak: You edit deleted answers... Really?

Comment: @Aditya - In Stack Overflow.

Comment: @hims056: I get that, he has 20k+ rep over there, so he can watch and edit deleted answers. But does he really edit them? It's just a waste of time IMHO... :)

Comment: @Aditya Oh right I thought this question was aboout editing a question in general

Comment: @Aditya It's usually just a CTRL-K

Comment: @jamylak: Right.. But.... :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no point editing an off-topic question on Meta. It will be closed and deleted very quickly (as has happened).

If a question is likely to be closed *but* you believe you can improve it, and possibly save it from being closed or help to re-open if it does get closed, *then* you should definitely edit.

Comment: Can't stress the last sentence enough; this is what your decision to edit should be based on. Ask yourself what impact your edit would make, if it's merely grammar on a completely off-topic question then don't waste your time.

Comment: P.S. That question is not appropriate for Stack Overflow. It just asks someone to provide code and barely explains what they're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it very well.

Comment: P.S. I only mentioned SO, because the question talks about pagination. I know that it is not appropriate to ask for code :)